# What setting could make the 'Show Toolbar' link disappear?

Tags: members, publish-layout

Is there some preference field or setting in the CP that might make the 'Show toolbar' link to disappear from the publish page? Mine has vanished for a particular custom member group (the only group that I'm using apart from Superadmins), although it shows up fine when I'm logged in as an SA. This made me think that it was something in the preference settings for that particular member group, but AFAICT nothing in that long settings list deals with the ability to customise publishing layouts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is by design. Only Super Admins can see the 'show toolbar' link on the publish page as this is mainly for administration. Generally you only want users to focus on the content and not the layout of the page.

You can however log in as Super Admin, make the changes to the publish page layout, save for the Member Group that the other user belongs to and then hit Save.

Comment: Ah, that explains it! When the docs talked about Publish Page Layouts being saved 'per member group' I wrongly assumed that you needed to log in as a specific member group to arrange them. A wood-for-the-trees moment. Thanks Ian.